# Rails 5 nested form find or create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, nested

I have two models `Run` and `Patient`.  `Run` belongs_to `Patient` and `Patient` has_many runs.

On the `Run` model I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes` in which to enter a patient's information into a run via a regular Rails form using fields_for.

Right now I have a basic form (stripped down version) that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@run) do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :patient do |p| %>
     <%= p.text_field :patient_name, placeholder: 'John Doe', class: 'form-control' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I'm able to create a patient inside of the form and reject the associated/nested object created inside of the model.  But what i'm looking to do is:

1.) Have a search/select box where I can type a patient name in and it will autocomplete

2.) If it finds the patient, it selects the patient and uses it for the run.

3.) If it does not find the patient or it's not the right patient, I'd like to be able to use `first_or_create` somehow to create the new patient record tied to the run.

I have searched for some examples on this and have come up short except an old Railscast espisode which wasn't very helpful and uses jQuery autocomplete which I'd like to avoid (use selectize or select2 instead).

I will continue working on examples that I find online, but any suggestions on how to do this is what I'm looking for.  I feel that I can instantiate the patients from a collection within the controller and use those in a selectize/select2 box to choose the patient and the associated nested field of patient_id.  So selecting the patient would not be a problem, but I'm unsure as to how to tackle the creation of a patient that does not match.

Comment: Note that requests for tutorials are off-topic here. Requests to "help you rewrite the code" are generally read as "rewrite the code for me", and that is not always well received on Stack Overflow. It is much better to ask smaller questions with the understanding that you'll be doing the work.

Comment: @halfer Understood, I will edit my question and elaborate a bit.  I've searched through Stack and come up short.

Comment: If you just want select existing Patients you can just use a select tag `<%= f.collection_select :patient_id, Patient.all, :id, :name %>`. You can then reject the nested attributes if `patient_id` is not nil. Far simpler than an autocomplete.

Comment: @max This is what I had in mind using selectize or select2 for a search box.  The problem is if the patient doesn't exist I need to be able to create them.  And what if there are two patients with the same name, that could be a problem.

Comment: Your application needs to be able to handle (and differentiate) between different patients with the same name.

Comment: @max Exactly that's why I will display in the collection the Patient Name and date of birth so that the end user knows the correct patient or to create another one.  I can handle differentiating the patients, but I'm still in need of figuring out how to do a find_or_create from within this form and do autocomplete where a patient is either found and selected or created if they are the wrong patient or does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

This answered my question:

https://gorails.com/episodes/select-or-create-with-selectize-js

I was able to get the behavior down that I needed using this.